# How do you change the sizes of a Gauge component in KendoReact?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-react-ui

The [documentation site](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/gauges/) has no information about changing the dimensions of the Gauges directly.

It seems like you're unable to change the Sizes or Dimensions of the Gauges created by Kendo. How can you change the size of the Guages?

Comment: either the program doesnt support sizing, or you could try manually setting the width and height of the elements in your processed HTML created by kendo-react-ui

(A bit hacky, but you can look into your html after the site has loaded, and select those elements in the page source, changing the outputs style)

Comment: tried setting the width and height of the elements, no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

> https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/gauges/styling/

You can change the inline-styles of your gauges like so:

```html
<kendo-radialgauge style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">

</kendo-radialgauge>
```

Changing the Width and Height Inline Styles, or by using a Stylesheet in your Website, you can change the size of a gauge.

Since these are custom HTML Elements that are Processed by kendo, I recommend adding an ID or Class to your pre-processed element, and selecting the id or class with css to style it later on.

Comment: the doc you refered is for angular, unfortunately I already tried the inline styles but it doesn't work